# Printing PDF file that's displayed in a WKWebView

Tags: swift, pdf, wkwebview, uiprintinteractioncntrler, uiprintformatter

I’m trying to print from a WKWebView. Webpages and images are working fine.

Only when I print a PDF file the pages are all blank.

This is the code I've used to create a printController:

```
let printController = UIPrintInteractionController.sharedPrintController()

let printInfo = UIPrintInfo(dictionary:nil)
printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputType.General
printInfo.jobName = urlField.text!
printInfo.duplex = UIPrintInfoDuplex.LongEdge

let formatter: UIViewPrintFormatter = webView.viewPrintFormatter()
formatter.contentInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)

printController.printFormatter = formatter
printController.printInfo = printInfo
printController.showsPageRange = true
printController.showsNumberOfCopies = true

printController.presentFromBarButtonItem(printButton, animated: true, completionHandler: nil)
```

Could someone help me into the right direction?
Is there a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPrintInteractionController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIPrintInteractionController/printingItem) you can use `printingItem`.

**IMPORTANT NOTE:** It is a bit laggy on the iPhone simulator and looks like it takes time to load pdf directly to the Controller.

But you need to set next code in `print` method

```
let printController = UIPrintInteractionController.sharedPrintController()

let printInfo = UIPrintInfo(dictionary:nil)
printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputType.General
printInfo.jobName = (webView.URL?.absoluteString)!
printInfo.duplex = UIPrintInfoDuplex.None
printInfo.orientation = UIPrintInfoOrientation.Portrait

//New stuff
printController.printPageRenderer = nil
printController.printingItems = nil
printController.printingItem = webView.URL!
//New stuff

printController.printInfo = printInfo
printController.showsPageRange = true
printController.showsNumberOfCopies = true

printController.presentFromBarButtonItem(printButton, animated: true, completionHandler: nil)
```

Example from simulator:[image]